# functional testing writing equivalence classes

Tags: functional-testing, equivalence-classes

Hey guy's i'm taking a software testing module and trying to study for the final coming up soon but having a little problem getting my head around some of it the question that was asked last year is

A large activist organisation uses an add-on to their email system for the purpose of calling
meetings. Any member who is authorised to do so only needs to send an email with the
following data in the Subject line in order to call a meeting:

Date +

Duration +

Location +

1{Agenda item}4

The date must be in the format dd/MMM/yy and the duration must be an integer between 1 and
4 hours, inclusive. (Assume the start time is always the same.) The location must be one of:

Limerick, Galway, Cork and Dublin - case does not matter. 
The agenda items must be no more
than 12 alphabetic characters each but the agenda must not be blank.
You are required to design test cases for this system using equivalence classes and boundary
value analysis. The design should be documented as follows:

(i) For each equivalence class you create you should specify its class number, its
description, whether it is valid/invalid and provide a specific example

How would i write a class for the date when its dd/MMM/yy for example ? 
any explanation of equivalence classes would also be much appreciated thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are

```
C1: 1 ≤ month ≤ 12
C2: 1 ≤ day ≤ 31
C3: 1812 ≤ year ≤ 2012
```

Thus based on valid values, the equivalence classes are:

```
M1= {month: 1 <- month <- 12}
D1 = {day: 1 <-day<<-31}
Y1= {year: 1812 <- year <- 2012}
```

Test Cases falling under this category are as under:

```
Test Case ID Month(mm) Day(dd) Year(yyyy) Expected Output
WR 2 -1 15 1912 Invalid Value of Month, as Month cannot be -ve
WR 3 13 15 1912 Invalid Value of Month, as Month is always < 12
WR 4 6 -1 1912 Invalid Value of Day, as Day cannot be -ve
WR 5 6 32 1912 Invalid Value of Day, as we cannot have 32 days in any month
WR 6 6 15 1811 Invalid Value of Year, as the rage is 1812 to 2012 only
WR 7 6 15 2013 Invalid Value of Year
```

More examples you can find here:
http://www.softwaretestinggenius.com/tutorial-7-to-generate-equivalence-class-test-cases-for-the-next-date-function

About Equivalence partitioning in Software testing you can read here http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-equivalence-partitioning-in-software-testing/